# Drupal 7 & Varnish 4 - I always get X-Drupal-Cache: MISS but X-Cache: HIT

Tags: caching, drupal-7, varnish, varnish-4, pressflow

I have run into the same issue as this person: [X-Drupal-Cache for Drupal 7 website always hits MISS](https://groups.drupal.org/node/325428), and can not find a way out.

I am running Drupal 7 - **Pressflow**

and

Varnish 4.0

When I curl I get this result:

```
TTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2016 17:45:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=db5fd757e7485622ac16af86f292603f51467999908; expires=Sat, 08-Jul-17 17:45:08 GMT; path=/; domain=.adland.tv; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
**X-Drupal-Cache: MISS**
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Language: en
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Jul 2016 17:41:27 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Varnish: 196743 3
Age: 213
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
**X-Cache: HIT**
X-Cache-Hits: 22
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 2bf55922d49b23d8-IAD
```

***isvarnishworking.com*** tells me: *"You deserve a gold star, here you go: gold star badge"*....

While the "Varnish Indicator Chrome Extension" suggested in the linked Drupal org thread, tells me Varnish missed, on every single page of my website regardless if I am logged in or not.

If I turn Drupal cache for anonymous users at admin/config/development/performance **off**, Varnish will not work at all. If I set different minimum cache lifetimes there, it makes no difference.

In my settings.php I have this:

```
$conf['varnish_version'] = 4;
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = True;
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('127.0.0.1');
$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;
$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 86400;
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/varnish/varnish.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_class_cache_page'] = 'VarnishCache';
$conf['reverse_proxy_header'] = 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR';
$conf['omit_vary_cookie'] = True;
$conf['drupal_http_request_fails'] = FALSE;
```

and this

```
 $conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/filecache/filecache.inc';
 $conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/authcache/authcache.cache.inc';
 $conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/authcache/modules/authcache_builtin/authcache_builtin.cache.inc';
 $conf['cache_class_cache_page'] = 'DrupalFileCache';
```

while this has been commented out from the Varnish config in settings.php because if I don't, Varnish fails:

```
//$conf['cache'] = 1;
//$conf['cache_lifetime'] = 01080;
```

I have turned off all modules that could interfere, such as captcha modules, and I will note that the statistics won't count node hits correctly now, so something is being cached...

The VCL I use is grabbed straight from [this github master with minimum changes](https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-4.0-configuration-templates/blob/master/default.vcl)

How can I troubleshoot this **X-Drupal-Cache: MISS** issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your backend is clearly sending cookies:

```
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=db5fd757e7485622ac16af86f292603f51467999908; expires=Sat, 08-Jul-17 17:45:08 GMT; path=/; domain=.adland.tv; HttpOnly
```

In default configuration, Varnish will not cache a object coming from the backend with a Set-Cookie header present. Also, if the client sends a Cookie header, Varnish will bypass the cache and go directly to the backend.

Comment: This was exactly the issue.

Comment: @CharlieBrown glad I could help. :) accept my answer plx.

Comment: I did as soon as I saw it, but I don't have high enough reputation for it to show